# Trying to backup Exchange Mailbox Store using Backup Exec 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, backupexec

I am trying to backup our Exchange Mailbox Store using Backup Exec 2010 R3 but when I select "Microsoft Information Store" and view the mailbox store it says that it is 0 KB in size.

Is there something that I need to do for it to actually show the true size of the mailbox store?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this wasn't quite what I was expecting. While Backup Exec shows the size of the mailbox store as being 0 KB when viewing the selections, when you actually back it up, it is the true size of the store.

Hopefully this will help somebody else with the same question somewhere down the road.

Answer (score 2):

do you have the Backup Exec Exchange Agent installed? Without this you won't be
able to backup the mailbox store properly.

Comment: I'm doing a test backup of the store and it may just be a problem with the way it displays the store size in the selection list. I'll still need to do a test restore but it appears to be backing up actual data so this may have been a false alarm...I will report back once I know for sure.